# Accessing Array inside jquery function 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a 2 Dimension Array.
I am trying to access it inside my Mousemove jquery function INSIDE my Canvas function. When i try so, i get the following error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
function Canvas(_canvas) {

            this.pixels = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i<this.canvas.width; i++) {
            var row = new Array();
            for (var j=0; j<this.canvas.height; j++) {
                row.push(i*j);      
            }
            this.pixels.push(row);  
        }

        $("#" + _canvas).mousemove(function(e){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            console.log(this.pixels[parseInt(e.clientX-offset.left)][parseInt(e.pageY-offset.top)]);  
        });



};
```

My array is accessible properly from any other function inside my Canvas function, except for the Jquery ones. Any thoughts on that ?

Thanks

Comment: you need to use the old `var that=this;` up top the constructor, and then use "that" in your mousemove handler to refer to the class instead of the element.

Comment: What does `console.log(this.pixels)` show?

Comment: @dandavis by up top the constructor, you mean the mousemove one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alias `this` into `that` to avoid ambiguity in the event handler between the instance and the event-raising element:

```
function Canvas(_canvas) {
            var that=this;
            this.pixels = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i<this.canvas.width; i++) {
            var row = new Array();
            for (var j=0; j<this.canvas.height; j++) {
                row.push(i*j);      
            }
            this.pixels.push(row);  
        }

        $("#" + _canvas).mousemove(function(e){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            console.log(that.pixels[parseInt(e.clientX-offset.left)][parseInt(e.pageY-offset.top)]);  
        });



};
```